Sign Program Method Transaction with Secret Key
I have a method in my program that can only be fired by the admin address. Now I am trying to fire this method using Next.js server actions using the secret key of the admin address. But I am having issues where the transaction is not being sent. I am facing errors like undefined blockhash and feepayer.
What am I missing?
"use server";

import { TokenVault } from "@/anchor/types/token_vault";
import token_vault_idl from "@/anchor/idl/token_vault.json";
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, BN, AnchorProvider, Idl } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import NodeWallet from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet";

export async function destake(tokenAccount: string) {
  const payer = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    //secret key here
  );
  const wallet = new NodeWallet(payer);

  const url = web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet");

  let connection = new web3.Connection(url, "confirmed");

  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
    commitment: "processed",
  });

  //Create Program Instance
  const programId = new web3.PublicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROGRAM_ID);
  const program = new Program(
    token_vault_idl as Idl,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROGRAM_ID,
    provider
  );

  const DUMMY_TOKEN_ADDRESS = new web3.PublicKey(
    "Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr"
  );

  //Create required PDAs
  const [tokenAccountOwnerPda] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("token_account_owner_pda")],
    programId
  );
  const [tokenVault] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("token_vault"), DUMMY_TOKEN_ADDRESS.toBuffer()],
    programId
  );
  const [stakeInfo] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("stake_info"), new web3.PublicKey(tokenAccount).toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  console.log("Stake Info", stakeInfo.toString());

  const destakeInstruction = await program.methods
    .destake(new BN(5 * 10 ** 6), payer.publicKey)
    .accounts({
      tokenAccountOwnerPda,
      vaultTokenAccount: tokenVault,
      stakeInfo: stakeInfo,
      mintOfTokenBeingSent: DUMMY_TOKEN_ADDRESS,
      senderTokenAccount: new web3.PublicKey(tokenAccount),
    })
    .signers([payer])
    .transaction();

  console.log(destakeInstruction);

  const txHash = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    destakeInstruction,
    [payer]
  );

  console.log("Transaction Hash", txHash);

  const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } =
    await program.provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();

  await program.provider.connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: txHash,
  });

  console.log(
    `Solana Explorer: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txHash}?cluster=devnet`
  );
}


Anchor program for reference
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{transfer, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer};
use solana_program::clock::Clock;
use solana_program::{pubkey, pubkey::Pubkey};

pub mod error;
pub mod states;
use crate::{error::*, states::*};

declare_id!("3kgj71kWEa5wFsKkNTjjyBX188zKT1X8ohY6KEst5Eg1");
pub const ADMIN: Pubkey = pubkey!("E6q6HeKopLXp447tcqScBFeiFDScHakK26TrTxqHbncE");

#[program]
mod token_vault {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn stake(ctx: Context<Stake>, amount: u64, stake_price: f32) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Stake amount: {}!", amount);

        let clock = Clock::get()?;

        let stake_info = &mut ctx.accounts.stake_info;
        stake_info.amount = amount;
        stake_info.staker = ctx.accounts.signer.key();
        stake_info.initial_stake_amount = amount;
        stake_info.stake_price = stake_price;
        stake_info.staking_time = clock.unix_timestamp;

        let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.sender_token_account.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.vault_token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            transfer_instruction,
        );

        transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn destake(ctx: Context<DeStake>, amount: u64, staker_address: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Destake amount: {}!", staker_address);

        let stake_info = &mut ctx.accounts.stake_info;

        if amount == 0 {
            return Err(error!(Errors::AmountZero));
        }

        if amount > stake_info.amount {
            return Err(error!(Errors::WithdrawAmountGreater));
        }

        if stake_info.amount == 0 {
            return Err(error!(Errors::StakeAmountZero));
        }

        let updated_amount = stake_info.amount.checked_sub(amount).unwrap();
        ctx.accounts.stake_info.amount = updated_amount;

        let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.vault_token_account.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.sender_token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.token_account_owner_pda.to_account_info(),
        };

        let bump = ctx.bumps.token_account_owner_pda;
        let seeds = &[b"token_account_owner_pda".as_ref(), &[bump]];
        let signer = &[&seeds[..]];

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            transfer_instruction,
            signer,
        );

        transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn delete_stake_acc(_ctx: Context<DeleteStakeAcc>, _staker_address: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    // Derived PDAs
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        seeds=[b"token_account_owner_pda".as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8
    )]
    token_account_owner_pda: Account<'info, TokenOwnerAccount>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        seeds=[b"token_vault".as_ref(), mint_of_token_being_sent.key().as_ref()],
        token::mint=mint_of_token_being_sent,
        token::authority=token_account_owner_pda,
        bump
    )]
    vault_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    mint_of_token_being_sent: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(mut)]
    signer: Signer<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Stake<'info> {
    // Derived PDAs
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        seeds=[b"stake_info", sender_token_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + StakeInfo::INIT_SPACE
    )]
    pub stake_info: Account<'info, StakeInfo>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds=[b"token_account_owner_pda"],
        bump
    )]
    token_account_owner_pda: Account<'info, TokenOwnerAccount>,

    #[account(mut,
        seeds=[b"token_vault", mint_of_token_being_sent.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint=mint_of_token_being_sent,
        token::authority=token_account_owner_pda,
    )]
    vault_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    sender_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    mint_of_token_being_sent: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(mut)]
    signer: Signer<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(staker_address: Pubkey)]
pub struct DeStake<'info> {
    // Derived PDAs
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds=[b"stake_info", sender_token_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub stake_info: Account<'info, StakeInfo>,

    #[account(mut,
        seeds=[b"token_account_owner_pda"],
        bump
    )]
    token_account_owner_pda: Account<'info, TokenOwnerAccount>,

    #[account(mut,
        seeds=[b"token_vault", mint_of_token_being_sent.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint=mint_of_token_being_sent,
        token::authority=token_account_owner_pda,
    )]
    vault_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    sender_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    mint_of_token_being_sent: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(mut, address = ADMIN @ Errors::NotAdmin)]
    signer: Signer<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(staker_address: Pubkey)]
pub struct DeleteStakeAcc<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds=[b"stake_info", staker_address.as_ref()],
        bump,
        close = signer
    )]
    pub stake_info: Account<'info, StakeInfo>,

    #[account(mut, address = ADMIN @ Errors::NotAdmin)]
    signer: Signer<'info>,
}



devnet was down and is still down at the time of writing this. Switch to testnet and check if it works.
devnet status updates twitter handle

Also checked with testnet

Can you please provide an example of achieving something like this.
